# Semantic UI React Dropdown is not working properly with tabindex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui, tabindex

I was trying to fix some accessibility issues in my project which are related to tabindex access. In my case, Semantic-UI Dropdown is not working as I expected with tabindex. When I access the UI using the TAB key, The dropdown automatically collapses and again I press the TAB key, then it will select the first option from the dropdown list. I have used tabindex attribute but it gets highlighted but not get collapse when I press the Enter from the keyboard. And also I cant select options that are in the dropdown list through the TAB key or arrow keys. Below is my sample code and I'm using semantic-ui-react module for this project.

```
<Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell className={styles.itemsTableHeader}>
              <Checkbox  onChange={()=>this.allItemsChkBoxOnChangeHandler()} label={<label><b>All</b></label>} id="allItems"/>
            </Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell textAlign='left' className={styles.itemsTableHeader + ' ' + styles.tbleCellNoBrdr}>
              Order:  {this.generateDropdown()}
            </Table.HeaderCell>
</Table.Row>



/**
  * Generate dropdown for ordering
  */
generateDropdown(){
    return (
        <Dropdown disabled={this.props.items.itemChanging} className={styles.orderDropDown} menu options={this.state.options} text={this.state.order} onChange={this.handleOrderDropdownChange} icon={<Icon name='angle down' className={styles.dropdownIcon + ' ' + styles.orderDropDown} middle aligned size='large'/>} floating>
        </Dropdown>
      );
  }
```